# jquery mobile: vertically center two lines of button text

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I have a jQuery mobile button with 2 lines of text with the following CSS rules:

```
.ui-btn-text {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

jQuery makes a span with the class: `ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all` around the text.

I want this element to be vertically centered.

When i use `vertical-align` it has no effect. `line-height` does not work either because my text can have two lines.

Does anyone have an idea how I can vertically center my text in the button?

[image: image of the compiled code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements (like `<SPAN>`) can only use `line-height` to fake vertical alignment. So if that won't work for you in this situation because of multiple lines, switch to a tables/cells (`<TD>`). But if jQuery mobile is generating the inner span tags, that won't work for you.

You could also vertical aligning the wrapper `<TD>` instead and make the button have a smaller height so the text itself doesn't need vertical centering. But that means visual design changes.

The HTML specification is not designed for that type of layout. So if the above solutions won't work in your situation, you'll have give up trying to dynamically vertically align text within an inline element, at least via HTML/CSS-only solutions.

Non-CSS solutions include pre-rendered images, Javascript adjustments after data-binding, HTML5 `<CANVAS>` or SVG images, and other advanced workarounds that usually aren't worth the hassle if all you want is vertically aligned text.

Comment: A good article regarding how to get around vertical centering issues: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html and http://www.student.oulu.fi/~laurirai/www/css/middle/

Answer (score 2):

You should make the container div

```
position: relative;
```

And give it a height. Then make the inner div

```
position: absolute; margin: 0px auto;
```

To make it vertically centered in the container!

=============
Original answer:

```
text-align: center;
```

Should do the trick for horizontal centering.

Answer (score 1):

Try with top bottom `padding: 10px 0;`

Answer (score 1):

i solved it by putting the text in a div with margin top, its not perfected centered now when it has 2 lines, but it should be fine. Thx for your suggestions